# LocalConnection StatusEvent Error

Tags: actionscript-3, localconnection

I'm getting this error intermittently when attempting to call functions in a localconnection.

```
Error #2044: Unhandled StatusEvent:. level=error, code=
```

The "handled" output:

```
LocalConnection.send() failed [StatusEvent type="status" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 code=null level="error"]
```

Here is the code that sends the info:

```
package facebook 
{
import flash.events.StatusEvent;
import flash.net.LocalConnection;

public class Leaderboard
{
    private var sendLC:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
    public var leaderboardScores:Object;
    public static var LB:Leaderboard;

    public function Leaderboard()
    {
        LB = this;
        sendLC.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusError);
    }
    public function showAbilities():void
    {
        var abilityArray:Array = [];
        for each (var o:Object in leaderboardScores)
        {
            var player:Array = [o[0], o[1], o[2], o[3].value];
            abilityArray.push(player);
        }
        abilityArray.sortOn([3], Array.NUMERIC);
        sendLC.send("_myConnection", "showAbilities", abilityArray);
        showDeaths();
    }
    public function showDeaths():void
    {
        var deathArray:Array = [];
        for each (var o:Object in leaderboardScores)
        {
            var player:Array = [o[0], o[1], o[2], o[4].value];
            deathArray.push(player);
        }
        deathArray.sortOn([3], Array.NUMERIC);
        sendLC.send("_myConnection", "showDeaths", deathArray);
        showChallenges();
    }
    public function showChallenges():void
    {
        var challengeArray:Array = [];
        for each (var o:Object in leaderboardScores)
        {
            var player:Array = [o[0], o[1], o[2], o[5].value];
            challengeArray.push(player);
        }
        challengeArray.sortOn([3], Array.NUMERIC);
        sendLC.send("_myConnection", "showChallenges", challengeArray);
        showMoney();
    }
    public function showMoney():void
    {
        var moneyArray:Array = [];
        for each (var o:Object in leaderboardScores)
        {
            var player:Array = [o[0], o[1], o[2], o[6].value];
            moneyArray.push(player);
        }
        moneyArray.sortOn([3], Array.NUMERIC);
        trace("! ! ! ! ! !SENDING MONEY ! ! ! ! ! !");
        sendLC.send("_myConnection", "showMoney", moneyArray);
        showBuffs();
    }
    public function showBuffs():void
    {
        var buffArray:Array = [];
        for each (var o:Object in leaderboardScores)
        {
            var player:Array = [o[0], o[1], o[2], o[7].value];
            buffArray.push(player);
        }
        buffArray.sortOn([3], Array.NUMERIC);
        sendLC.send("_myConnection", "showBuffs", buffArray);
        showKills();
    }
    public function showKills():void
    {
        var killArray:Array = [];
        for each (var o:Object in leaderboardScores)
        {
            var player:Array = [o[0], o[1], o[2], o[8].value];
            killArray.push(player);
        }
        killArray.sortOn([3], Array.NUMERIC);
        sendLC.send("_myConnection", "showKills", killArray);
    }
    private function statusError(e:StatusEvent):void
    {
        switch (e.level) {
            case "status":
                trace( "LocalConnection.send() succeeded");
                break;
            case "error":
                trace( "LocalConnection.send() failed " +e);
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the recieving code:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.LocalConnection;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source='../assets/leaderboardOutline.png')]
    private var outlineClass:Class;

    private var receiverLC:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection()
    private var background:Bitmap = new outlineClass;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        receiverLC.client = this;
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        try 
        {
            this.receiverLC.allowDomain('*')
            this.receiverLC.connect("_myConnection");
            trace('!~~~~~LocalConnection SUCCEEDED');
        } 
        catch (error:ArgumentError) 
        {
            trace('!~~~~~~LocalConnection FAILURE');
        }
        addChild(background);
    }
    public function showAbilities(scores:Array):void
    {
        trace("ABILITIES\n");
        try{
            for each (var a:Array in scores)
                trace("NAME: " + a[1] + " SCORE: " + a[3]);
        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            trace("Error " + e);
        }
    }
    public function showDeaths(scores:Array):void
    {
        trace("DEATHS\n");
        try{
            for each (var a:Array in scores)
                trace("NAME: " + a[1] + " SCORE: " + a[3]);
        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            trace("Error " + e);
        }
    }
    public function showChallenges(scores:Array):void
    {
        trace("CHALLENGES\n");
        try{
            for each (var a:Array in scores)
                trace("NAME: " + a[1] + " SCORE: " + a[3]);
        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            trace("Error " + e);
        }
    }
    public function showMoney(scores:Array):void
    {
        trace("MONEY\n");
        try{
            for each (var a:Array in scores)
                trace("NAME: " + a[1] + " SCORE: " + a[3]);
        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            trace("Error " + e);
        }
    }
    public function showBuffs(scores:Array):void
    {
        trace("BUFFS\n");
        try{
            for each (var a:Array in scores)
                trace("NAME: " + a[1] + " SCORE: " + a[3]);
        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            trace("Error " + e);
        }
    }
    public function showKills(scores:Array):void
    {
        trace("KILLS\n");
        try{
            for each (var a:Array in scores)
                trace("NAME: " + a[1] + " SCORE: " + a[3]);
        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            trace("Error " + e);
        }
    }
}   
 }
```

The searching I've done on the error seems to be of little value. Most people say that declaring the localconnection outside of the function fixed it for them. Can anyone see anything that could cause this error?

Comment: post the error not the StatusEvent

Comment: Error #2044: Unhandled StatusEvent:. level=error, code=

Comment: You are handling the event so this is odd.

Comment: If I handle the event it will post what is under the "handled" event title above. The unhandled error will only post if I remove the listener.

Comment: of course it will you need that listener because that event will always be triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much information is being passed to the local swf. If you need to change the data quickly create separate LocalConnections for each of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few things that might be an issue.

First is the flow the way you have it set up the sender would have to be loaded before the receiver. Since the receiver is not wrapped in a try/catch you have no idea if it actually connected.

```
private function connect( ):void{
  try {
    this.receiverLC.allowDomain('*')
    this.receiverLC.connect("_myConnection");
    trace('LocalConnection SUCCEEDED')
  } catch (error:ArgumentError) {
    trace('LocalConnection FAILURE')
  }
}
```

Next is that your status events poorly.

```
private function statusError(e:StatusEvent):void {
  switch (e.level) {
    case "status":
      trace( "LocalConnection.send() succeeded");
      break;
    case "error":
      trace( "LocalConnection.send() failed " );
      break;
  }
}
```

And last you need to have the swfs cross talk back and forth so the sender will know the other swf is ready.

[EDIT]
In the following function you are assigning o[4] but in the call back function you are accessing o[3] which doesnt exist.

```
    public function showDeaths():void
    {
        var deathArray:Array = [];
        for each (var o:Object in leaderboardScores)
        {

// here is one problem o[4] in showDeaths you are looking for 3
            var player:Array = [o[0], o[1], o[2], o[4].value];
            deathArray.push(player);
        }
        deathArray.sortOn([3], Array.NUMERIC);
        sendLC.send("_myConnection", "showDeaths", deathArray);
        showChallenges();
    }
```

All but the first of your call backs are plagued with the same issue

Comment: The receiving SWF will always be ready first as it is a 20kb SWF and the other one is 20MB.

Comment: I should also mention that I am able to call the functions. Before I had it run through all the functions in the receiving SWF and the first two would run before throwing the error.

Comment: I wouldn't count on size as a factor since things can/will be cached.

Comment: Did you at least add my code? It would behoove you to implement it since you have absolutely zero error handling in your code. No error handling ===== No debugging capacity.

Comment: I've been working on crash bugs over the last couple days. I will add your code in the near future.

Comment: OK, I have updated the code. The sending of the code does not happen till 30-40 seconds after the SWF is loaded. This is not affected by caching.

The first three execute properly. The last two have the error above.

Comment: Is this getting traced? trace('!~~~~~LocalConnection SUCCEEDED');

Comment: Yes it is. I'm stumped why the first ones work and the rest fail.

Comment: Then the only thing it can be is there is a bug in the function that you are calling in the receiving SWF

Comment: Try bringing back to basics. just pass a string and see if it works

Comment: No that isn't it. The Player array would look like this:
player[0] = o[0], 
player[1] = o[1], 
player[2] = o[2], 
player[3] = o[4].value;

Therefore a[3] is the correct index to show o[4].value

Comment: God I feel stupid for that one. Anyway have you verified that the data being sent is the same as what is received? Try putting a break on the send function. And have a look at the array of array you are sending.

Comment: They all check out when being sent.

Comment: LocalConnection.send() succeeded
LocalConnection.send() succeeded
LocalConnection.send() succeeded
LocalConnection.send() failed [StatusEvent type="status" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 code=null level="error"]
LocalConnection.send() failed [StatusEvent type="status" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 code=null level="error"]
LocalConnection.send() failed [StatusEvent type="status" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 code=null level="error"]